# Is there any way to give your animal companion the constrict ability if they don't already have it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions

Is it possible for an animal companion to gain the constrict ability, if they don't naturally start with it or gain it at level 4 or 7? Are there any feats, items, or any other means of acquiring this ability?

Comment: Please keep in mind that list questions are off topic here.  This isn't exactly a list question as worded but it is close and it has attracted a list answer (not that there's anything wrong with a list in an answer).  If your question really was 'what are all the ways to do this' rather than 'can this be done' then this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible

However, there are few ways to obtain constrict. The feats that can grant constrict have requeriments that an animal companion cannot meet, like being a [naga/serpentfolk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/final-embrace-combat/) or an [ogre](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ogre-crush/).

### Magic Items

Both the [Backbreaker's Mail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/backbreaker-mail/) and the [Anaconda's Coils](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-anaconda-s-coils/) will grant constrict to the wearer and are items that can be used by animal companions. There are other items, such as the [Constrictor Gauntlets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/constrictor-s-gauntlets/), but they require certain actions or body slots that may not be available for animals.

Note that the armor is usually shaped for humanoids, so you might need a blacksmith to suit it to your companion's body (also, ask your GM if he allows that).

### Spells

The polymorph subschool spells will all grant the *constrict* ability if the form assumed has it. But these spells may not be easily accessible to your character depending on his class, as they are mostly available to alchemists, bloodragers, magi, sorcerers and wizards. While Vermin Shape is also available to druids and witches.

- [Beast Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape/), [Monstrous Physique](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/monstrous-physique-i/), [Undead Anatomy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undead-anatomy-i/), [Vermin Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vermin-shape-i/), and [Plant Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plant-shape-i/).

Although it is not exactly *constrict*, the result of the spell [Vine Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vine-strike/) is similar to the *constrict* ability: an additional 1d6 damage, target is entangled if they fail a reflex save. Being personal, most classes with an animal companion will allow you to cast this on the companion.